# 'cut' output redirect to c++ program

Tags: c++, bash, pipe

I am trying to change the output of command `ping` using `cut` to get some necessary information for me and then redirect it to c++ program with bash pipes.

```sh
ping google.com | cut -d " " --fields 8 | ./a.out
```

C++ program doing such stuff:

```cpp
int main(){
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cout << "str:" << str << endl;
}
```

I suggested, that such command might work, but it doesn't, there is no any output after executing the command above. But it works nicely without using `cut`. If I use only

```sh
ping google.com | ./a.out
```

my program does output. So I think the problem is my c++ program can't read strings from `cut`.

How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Your C++ program will happily read fom `cut` or any other program, that's piped in on standard input. Whatever your real problem is, it's not what you think it is, but without more information it is unlikely that anyone will have any idea what it is.

Comment: What is "such stuff"? I don't understand what you're trying to do with your C++ program and how it relates to the command-line above it.

Comment: @einpoklum without going into details, the problem is to read string.

Comment: @elo: Your program doesn't know that it's getting output from `cut`. Try adding a [`tee`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178752/using-tee-to-output-intermediate-results-to-stdout-instead-of-files) to see what actually happens

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I can provide any additional information. After entering the command from the question there is no any output.

Comment: So? You can provide it any time. You don't need anyone's permission to do that, you can [edit] your question any time.

Comment: The output of `ping google.com | cut -d " " --fields 8` starts with an empty. `cin` reads the empty line, it is printed and your program ends.

Comment: @ThomasSablik if I put ```cin >> str``` into ```while(true)``` loop, there is no any output anyway.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, it doesn't read happily from `cut`. I reproduced it as described and the program doesn't read anything

Comment: Did you happen to notice, @ThomasSablik, that the first output from `ping` does not have an 8th field? So `cut` simply produced an empty line, containing every last byte of the empty field, and the C++ program correctly read the empty line, and displayed it, and since it's coded to show only the first read line, that's what happened. The C++ program had no problems reading `cut`s output, and simply read what `cut` wrote: an empty line. Have a nice day!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, it doesn't even read the empty line. It blocks and doesn't finish. You can add a loop. The program doesn't pass the first `cin`. You don't even need the program. `ping google.com | cut -d " " --fields 8 | tee` doesn't print anything

Comment: Output buffering means that `a.out` will only receive input once 1-8KB of output has accumulated or `cut` exits.

Comment: Your version of `cut` simply must be not flushing its stdout at the end of every line, and it will wait until 8192 bytes, or so, have been generated, before flushing its output buffer. At that point, the C++ program will then read its line. There is no issues with the C++ code, or cut.

Comment: Why does `cut` write to console and flushes after each line but if I pipe it into another program it doesn't flush?

Comment: @ThomasSablik stdout is line buffered when it's connected a [tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html), full buffered otherwise. libc does this, so it applies to nearly every Linux program. See http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/.

Comment: @JohnKugelman So `ping` is line buffered and `cut` is full buffered?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yeah, `ping` flushes its output every line. I'm guessing it has manual `fflush(stdout)` calls, or changes the buffering with `setvbuf()`. Or doesn't use stdio.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thank you. I suppose this is a very important information and it's good to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `ping` utility is line-buffered (it does [`fflush(stdout)`](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping/ping.c#L1372) after outputting each line).

You can instead set the entire pipeline to use line-buffering by using the `stdbuf` command from GNU coreutils:

```
stdbuf -oL -eL bash -c 'ping google.com | cut -d " " --fields 8 | ./a.out'
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman It runs the whole pipeline under stdbuf. Of course, running just `cut` alone would be sufficient in this case.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I didn't realize that [stdbuf affects subprocesses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279984/stdbuf-supposed-behavior-for-subprocesses).